# how to tell if a mysql insert is successful using while loop?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am inserting the records in mysql database using while loop.I want to chcek the check atleast one record is inserted or not. I tried below code but ROW_COUNT() give me success, if the record is not inserted.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test$$
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
   DECLARE count INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE res varchar(255);
   WHILE count < 10 DO
      /**Sql statement**/
      SET count = count + 1;
   END WHILE;
   IF ROW_COUNT() > 0 THEN 
        SET res = 'success';
    ELSE
       SET res = 'failure';
    END IF;
    SELECT res;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You removed the important part. Present a [MCVE].

Comment: Have you read [the semantics of `ROW_COUNT()` in the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//information-functions.html#function_row-count)? Do they match your expectations/assumptions? Presumably if you did not perform any `INSERT` then `ROW_COUNT()` tells you about whatever operation you did prior; it doesn't know about your loop or about your intentions. Why aren't you using `count`? What is your goal?